# Can I use home internet wireless router as wireless receiver?

Tags: router, wireless-router, internet-sharing

I have Cisco [linksys E900](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/E900). I need to use this router for my desktop as wireless receiver. My intension is to receive internet connection broadcasted by my Lumia Windows phone.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know your specific router model but these devices can usually only act as _access points,_ i.e. they are the hub and not a node in your wireless network. A receiver is a different device. I think you need to make a purchase.

Comment: You basically want to make the router into an extender which is indeed possible but not with the default firmware.  If flashed with the DD-WRT firmware what you want should be possible.  A WiFI extender can have 10/100/1000 ports which the E900 as.  I would agree with Torben just buying a USB reciever might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The [Linksys FAQ for the E900](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=62a624670c244f329169e0837adec576_KB_EN_v1.xml) doesn't mention the option to use it as a wireless repeater, like some other routers support. It can act as a wireless bridge, but apparently only by connecting it to another router's wired Ethernet cable.